# Very simple problem regarding shifting of a signal

Tags: signal-analysis, continuous-signals

I have this simple $x(t)$ graph, and I have some confusion regarding time shifting.

[image]

What is the graph of $x(1-t)$ ?

Answer (score 3):

Don't look at graphs and don't think of "flip and slide" as your
instructor/TA will tell you is the way to solve such problems.

$x(\cdot)$ is a function that has value $5$ whenever what
is between the "$($" and the "$)$" has value between $-4$ and $4$.  So, $x(1-t)$
has value $5$ exactly when

$$ -4 \leq 1-t \leq 4 \quad \Rightarrow \quad t \in [a, b]$$

where $a$ and $b$ are numbers (hint: they are integers!) that I will
leave for you to work as an exercise. When you are done, you can easily
sketch $x(1-t)$  from this information.

Comment: so, is it -3<=t<=5 ?